# Manipulating background image background-size: cover

Tags: css

This is regarding the header background image over at --> http://www.lorenzopierucci.com/process

This is what it looks like in most resolutions -->
[image: Normal]

**But, it looks a bit off on very large resolution monitors**

[image: The head is cut off]

It only shows his forehead. I'd like to use media queries to fix that, but am having trouble actually manipulating the image.

How would you manipulate the background image, to move it so at least his eyes show?

To look at any of the code, feel free to peruse on http://www.lorenzopierucci.com/process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set

```
background-position-y: 30%;
```

(or something in this line, try different percentages).

If the image isn't being clipped vertically, it will show as is.

If the image is being clipped vertically, it will *center* in the point that you have specified.

This is a personal decision, but I would focus it on the eyes (that I estimate in about 30% - 40%)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, dohp --> Changed the background property from :

```
background: url(assets/img/lorenzo_procc.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

to

```
background: url(assets/img/lorenzo_procc.jpg) no-repeat center center;
```